# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block... CRT detected that the application worte to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++, native

When I run this code, I get the error in the title, here's an exact screenshot:

[image]

My code is this :

```
string ProcessCommand(vector<unsigned char> data)
{
    try
    {
        int valread = data.size();
        unsigned char* converted = &data[0];
        char *buffer = (char *)converted;
        buffer[valread] = '\0';
        const char file[] = ">myfile.txt";
        char * newBuffer = new char[strlen(buffer) + strlen(file) + 1];
        strcpy(newBuffer, buffer);
        strcat(newBuffer, file);
        system(newBuffer);
        fstream f("myfile.txt", fstream::in);
        string str;
        getline(f, str, '\0');
        //const char * sendfile = str.c_str();
        //char * result;
        //result = const_cast<char *>(sendfile);
        f.close();
        remove("myfile.txt");
        return str;
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn to format code.

Comment: `buffer[valread] = '\0';` is off by one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I formatted your question for you. Next time, take a moment to do this yourself, since a preview option is available to you when posting. Respect the people who you'd like to answer your question, by not posting a complete mess for them to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buffer[valread] = '\0';` is attempting to access an element of `buffer` that doesn't exist. The program behaviour is therefore undefined.

If you had used `data.at(valread)` instead then a `std::exception` would have been thrown (and intercepted at your `catch` site), as required by the C++11 standard.

Also consider using the `+` overload of `std::string` for all your concatenations. Your code will be so much more readable if you do that. Use a `std::string` type for `newBuffer` (with automatic storage duration) as well. You can always use `c_str()` to access the internal data buffer on a read-only basis.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this is 2017, shouldn't we encourage C++14 adoption? As it is the current standard.

Comment: Dude, I've only just moved my toolchain to C++11 ;-) But you might have a point here.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Given the overweight added to the standard at every new edition, I've got a feeling that by 2020 you'll be encouraging to move to Java or go back to C.

Comment: Yes.  Just `static const char file[] = "myfile.txt"; const std::string buffer(data.begin(), data.end()); const std::string newBuffer = buffer + ">" + file;system(newBuffer.c_str());` makes things much simpler.

Comment: @barakmanos - I don't see *that* many changes to core languages in 14 and 17. Mostly defect fixes. And the modifications to the standard library are always welcome in my book. Seeing as I'm excited for Concepts (and hold my fingers cross for them in C++2x), I don't see myself changing my tune soon :)

Comment: @Bathsheba - Would you mind if I post your comment on my profile (with attribution, of course)? That is the best thing I heard today. :D

Comment: tanks very much...! exactly